# swift AVCapturePhotoOutput capturePhoto hangs preview

Tags: ios, swift, ios-camera

Showing preview in 1080 x 1440; getting photo with max resolution (3024 x 4032) and quality on iPhone 8 Plus with code:

```
capturePhotoOutput?.capturePhoto(with: configurePhotoSettings(), delegate: self)
```

with photo settings:

```
private func configurePhotoSettings() -> AVCapturePhotoSettings {
    let photoSettings = AVCapturePhotoSettings()
    photoSettings.isHighResolutionPhotoEnabled = true
    photoSettings.isAutoStillImageStabilizationEnabled = (capturePhotoOutput?.isStillImageStabilizationSupported)!
    photoSettings.isAutoDualCameraFusionEnabled = (capturePhotoOutput?.isDualCameraFusionSupported)!
        
    return photoSettings
}
```

Doing this one by one (like sequential shooting mode) and preview freezes each time for a short time even if I do nothing in `didFinishProcessingPhoto`.

---

Looking for solution to make capturing smooth, maybe in background thread, but currently I'm stuck..

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: @HuangJie please look at my answer bellow in this topic

Comment: got it, thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason of preview hangs is feature called **optical stabilization**.

---

You just need to turn it off for smooth preview while capturing photo:

```
photoSettings.isAutoStillImageStabilizationEnabled = false
```